# Link SVG elements so they move at once?

Tags: svg

I would like to "group" SVG points that belong to elements.
What I want is very simple, but I am not sure that SVG supports this:

```
  <polyline stroke-width="7" stroke="#f4c76b" points="70,0 120,0" />
  <polyline stroke-width="7" stroke="#af41f4" points="120,0 200,0" />
  <circle stroke-width="1" r="3" cx="120" cy="0" stroke="black" fill="white" />
```

Here there are two lines, from 70,0 to 120,0 and 120,0 to 200,0. Which means where one finishes, the other starts. At that point, (120,0), there is a circle. I would like to add some thing in the SVG file such that, when I open it in an editor like Inkscape, if I move the circle to (120,10) the SVG becomes:

```
  <polyline stroke-width="7" stroke="#f4c76b" points="70,0 120,10" />
  <polyline stroke-width="7" stroke="#af41f4" points="120,10 200,0" />
  <circle stroke-width="1" r="3" cx="120" cy="10" stroke="black" fill="white" />
```

That is, the outer extremities of the lines remained in place, but the ones overlapping with the circle actually followed the circle.
I am actually not even sure this is possible in SVG.

I have read [this](https://www.sarasoueidan.com/blog/structuring-grouping-referencing-in-svg/) about linking SVG elements, but this is not exactly what I want.

Comment: Put them all in a <g> element and translate that

Comment: Thanks. But if I use <g>, the entire polylines will move. I only want one of the endpoints of each polyline to move. Notice the "points" field in the first and second extracy fo code :)

Comment: You would have to write code to do that

Comment: As in I would have to create my own svg editor? Is there no tag or anything in SVG format to allow this?

Comment: You could write something in JavaScript to do it

Comment: Inkscape has a [connector tool](http://tavmjong.free.fr/INKSCAPE/MANUAL/html/Connectors.html). It is not pure SVG, but does what you want.

Comment: @RobertLongson, thanks I'll look into this.

Comment: @ccprog: I tried, but it's not quite what I want. It does draw the connector, but as a new element, it won't make the line tilt to match the point.